# How to add a "File" type to my data in vuejs with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

**My code:**

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  type: string;
  description: string;
}

data() {
  return {
    id: "",
    item: {} as Item,
    file: //Here
  };
}
```

Hello, I'm looking to add a File type to my vuejs data.

I saw this solution that could work:

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  type: string;
  description: string;
  file: File;
}

data() {
  return {
    id: "",
    item: {} as Item
  };
}
```

but I don't want to add my data file to my Item interface or in an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an `interface` (or a `type`) to data itself and just add the `file` property to it.

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  type: string;
  description: string;
}

interface State {
  id: string;
  item: Item;
  file: null | File;
}

data(): State {
  return {
    id: '',
    item: {
      title: '',
      type: '',
      description: '',
    },
    file: null,
  };
},
```